# Meteor + React Iterating documents inside User

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a few days with meteor + react and I'm stuck trying to display a list of documents inside users collection.

Each Meteor.user has an array of "Customers" object inside. I'm able to insert new customers inside the user, but not iterating over this.

This is my component code:

CustomersForm.js

```
export class CustomersForm extends Component {

  addCustomer(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = this.refs.name.value.trim();
    const rut = this.refs.rut.value.trim();
    const phone = this.refs.phone.value.trim();
    const mail = this.refs.mail.value.trim();
    const website = this.refs.website.value.trim();
    const contact = this.refs.contact.value.trim();
    const socialmean = this.refs.socialmean.value.trim();

    if (name !== '' && rut !== '') {
      Meteor.call('insertNewCustomer',name,rut,socialmean,phone,mail,website,contact,(err, res) => {
        if(!err) {
          this.refs.name.value = '';
          this.refs.rut.value = '';
          this.refs.phone.value = '';
          this.refs.mail.value = '';
          this.refs.website.value = '';
          this.refs.contact.value = '';
          this.refs.socialmean.value = '';

        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Clientes  </h1>
        <form className='new-items' onSubmit={this.addCustomer}>
          Nombre :<input type='text' ref='name' defaultValue='Carovestuario' /> <br/>          
          RUT :<input type='text' ref='rut' defaultValue='76037806-2' /> <br/>
          Razon Social : <input type='text' ref='socialmean' defaultValue='Algodon y poliester LTDA'/><br/>
          Telefono : <input type='text' ref='phone' defaultValue='2257144709'/><br/>
          Mail : <input type='text' ref='mail' defaultValue='pedidos@carovestuario.cl'/><br/>
          Pagina web : <input type='text' ref='website' defaultValue='carovestuario.cl'/><br/>
          Contacto(opcional) : <input type='text' ref='contact' defaultValue='Carolina Molina'/><br/>
          <button type='submit'>Crear Cliente</button>
        </form>
        <h1>Listado Clientes  </h1>
          {
            this.props.customers.map((item) => {
            return <Customer item={item} key={item._id} />
          })}
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default createContainer(({params}) => {
  let itemsSub = Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
  let itemsArray;
  itemsArray = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()}).customers.fetch();
  return {
    ready: itemsSub.ready(),
    customers: itemsArray
  }
}, CustomersForm);
```

Customer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Customers from '../api/Customers';

export default class Customer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='item'>
        <div className='vote-one' >
          <span>{this.props.item.name}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

main.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import Items from '../imports/api/Items';
import Customers from '../imports/api/Customers';

import '../imports/server/accounts';

Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {
    fields: {
      roles: 1,
      customers: 1
    }
  });
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

Error is in the container : TypeError: Cannot read property 'customers' of undefined

Minimongo can see User.customers and I tried by many ways to get to the customers array but I cant figure out how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is shown in the [createContainer](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer) example

You have to check that the subscription is ready and if the object has been found before accessing the data

```
  const itemsSub = Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
  const ready = itemsSub.ready();
  const user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
  const userExist = ready && !!user;

  return {
    ready,
    customers: (userExist) ? user.customers : []
  }
```

Comment: Hello and thanks, but I'm getting the same error : Cannot read property 'customers' of undefined. Maybe should I try to use another collection to store everything and keep Meteor.users for login details?

Comment: that is weird, have you debugged or logged to check what fields that user object has?

Comment: Checked log again and got TypeError: user.customers.fetch is not a function , then removed .fetch and worked!. Not sure if I will have problems in future steps, what do you think?